# Solve following summation using Binomial theorem

Tags: algebra-precalculus, summation, binomial-coefficients, binomial-theorem

I apologise in advance for posting another one of these homework assignment-questions; this one is pissing me off.

The question is: solve $\sum_{k=0}^n {{n \choose k}} k 4^k $ using the binomial theorem.

The deadline for the homework assignment is already long past (it wasn't mandatory); I just really want to figure out what the deal is here. Any tips are very welcome!

Comment: Hello, just one comment. I will post a solution but this is important: The expression you have is not an equation. It is just a mathematical expression. An equation occurs when you say something equals something and you don't know the value of one of the terms involved, Your expression has no equality to other thing.

Comment: You're completely right: frustration over not seeing the way to proceed made my formulation sloppy. I'll be clearer in the future!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}k4^k
&=4n\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n-1}{k-1}4^{k-1}\\
&=4n5^{n-1}
\end{align}
$$
In general
$$
\binom{n}{k}k(k-1)\cdots(k-j+1)=\binom{n-j}{k-j}n(n-1)\cdots(n-j+1)
$$

Comment: You beat me to it :).

Comment: Thanks, but I still don't see what property allows for this equality: $\sum _{k=0}^n {n\over k} k 4^k = 4n \sum_{k=0}^n {(n-1)\over (k-1)} 4^{k-1}.$ I realize that anything over a negative number is 0, but would like to understand the property that allows you to take the $k$ out as you did.
Side note: the textbook I have is very concise.

Comment: $\binom{n}{k}\ne\frac nk$. The binomial coefficient $\binom{n}{k}=\frac{n(n-1)(n-2)\cdots(n-k+1)}{k!}$. Therefore, $$\begin{align} \binom{n}{k}k &= \frac{n(n-1)(n-2)\cdots(n-k+1)}{k!}k\\ &=n\frac{(n-1)(n-2)(n-3)\cdots(n-k+1)}{(k-1)!}\\ &=n\binom{n-1}{k-1} \end{align} $$

Comment: Thanks very much. The ${n \over k}$ was a mistake: I wrote \over instead of ${n \choose k}$.

Answer (score 1):

Making the problem more general, consider $$\sum_{k=0}^n {{n \choose k}} k\, x^k=x\sum_{k=0}^n {{n \choose k}} k\, x^{k-1}=x\left(\sum_{k=0}^n {{n \choose k}} \, x^{k}\right)'$$ and $$\sum_{k=0}^n {{n \choose k}} \, x^{k}=(1+x)^n$$ $$\left(\sum_{k=0}^n {{n \choose k}} \, x^{k}\right)'=n\,(1+x)^{n-1}$$ which finally makes$$\sum_{k=0}^n {{n \choose k}} k\, x^k=n\,x\,(1+x)^{n-1}$$ Now, make $x=4$.